# GroupBy / Sum query issue with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Hello I have question with Queries in Entity Framework

My Parent Item is `workorders`

My child item is `workorderitems`

I would like to select all items from the `workorderitems` table where the `workorder_id` column matches my varialble (myid). The results should be grouped by by Item Name and the Quantity should be summed.

Also if I remove the `GroupBy` and `Select` statements, the query does return back results
However with the `GroupBy` and `Select` statements I get an error.

Below is my syntax:

```
var workorderitems= DBContext.WorkOrderItems
.Where(o => o.workorder_id == myid)
.GroupBy(grp => new { grp.ItemName })
.Select(result => new { itemname = result.Key.ItemName, qty = result.Sum(o => o.ItemQuantity) });



   var mycount = workorderitems.Count();
```

Can someone let me know if my synatax seems correct?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  I would think this means the query didnt return a value?

Comment: It means it crashed before returning any values.

Comment: So the database provider i am using does not support GroupBy or Sum.  is there any way around this?

Comment: You could try adding ToList() after the where clause. Then the groupby and select would be handled by C# instead of your database provider.

Comment: Beautiful That worked like a charm. I had do it in two steps. first executing just the .where and tolist.  Then take that result and us the group and sum

Comment: One more issue.  Now that i have the results in a list that only has two columns,  ItemName and ItemQuantity it is an anonymous type.  I need to loop through each item and extract values.

Comment: foreach(var workorderitem in workorderitems)... if you try this you should see that workorderitem knows it contains itemname, and qty properties... but if you're just looping through an anonymous object to create a concrete item, why not just create the concrete item instead in your select statement?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to use a separate Select, by using one of the overloads of the GroupBy method, you can use the 'keySelector' and 'resultSelector' parameters to combine both the group and sum.

GroupBy is a really powerful method that can be quite daunting at first, but once you get your head around it's fairly straight forward and extremely versatile.

Here's an example, it creates a List of WorkOrderItems, one for each group, with the results aggregated in; rather than returning a List of anonymous objects. You could extend this with multiple key selectors (group by clauses) and do all manner of summing and manipulation of the resulting object(s)...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myItems = new List<WorkOrderItem>
        {
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 1, ItemName = "A", ItemQuantity = 0 },
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 0, ItemName = "A", ItemQuantity = 1 },
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 0, ItemName = "A", ItemQuantity = 2 },
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 0, ItemName = "B", ItemQuantity = 3 },
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 0, ItemName = "B", ItemQuantity = 4 },
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 1, ItemName = "B", ItemQuantity = 5 },
            new WorkOrderItem { OrderId = 0, ItemName = "C", ItemQuantity = 6 },
        };

        int myId = 0;

        List<WorkOrderItem> groupedItems =
            myItems.Where(i => i.OrderId == myId)
                    .GroupBy(
                        //key selector
                        i => i.ItemName,
                        //result selector
                        (name, items) =>
                        {
                            var aggregatedItem = new WorkOrderItem
                            {
                                OrderId = myId,
                                ItemName = name,
                                ItemQuantity = items.Sum(i => i.ItemQuantity)
                            };
                            return aggregatedItem;
                        })
                        .ToList();


    }

    class WorkOrderItem
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For further reading on one of the most underrated methods in Linq I'd highly recommend taking a look at this blog post by Jon Skeet:
http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/